# How do you setup form POST with names/values and files with libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl

This is my code:

```
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string response;
    struct curl_httppost *formpost = NULL;
    struct curl_httppost *lastptr = NULL;
    struct curl_slist *headerlist = NULL;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl_formadd(&formpost,
                 &lastptr,
                 CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "curuserid",
                 CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, curuserid.toStdString().c_str(),
                 CURLFORM_END);

    curl_formadd(&formpost,
                 &lastptr,
                 CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "token",
                 CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, token.toStdString().c_str(),
                 CURLFORM_END);

    curl_formadd(&formpost,
                 &lastptr,
                 CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "macaddress",
                 CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, macaddress.toStdString().c_str(),
                 CURLFORM_END);

    curl_formadd(&formpost,
                 &lastptr,
                 CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "channelsrc",
                 CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, channelsrc.toStdString().c_str(),
                 CURLFORM_END);

    curl_formadd(&formpost,
                 &lastptr,
                 CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "bless",
                 CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, bless.toStdString().c_str(),
                 CURLFORM_END);

    curl_formadd(&formpost,
                 &lastptr,
                 CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "version",
                 CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, version.toStdString().c_str(),
                 CURLFORM_END);

    curl_formadd(&formpost,
                 &lastptr,
                 CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "deviceid",
                 CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, deviceid.toStdString().c_str(),
                 CURLFORM_END);


//    curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr,

//                 CURLFORM_PTRNAME, "image",
//                 CURLFORM_FILENAME, "sample.png",
//                 CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "image/png",
////                 CURLFORM_PTRCONTENTS, image.c_str(),
////                 CURLFORM_CONTENTSLENGTH, image.size(),
//                 CURLFORM_BUFFERPTR, image.c_str(),
//                 CURLFORM_BUFFERLENGTH, image.size(),

//                 CURLFORM_END);

//    curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr,

//                 CURLFORM_PTRNAME, "imgdata\0",
//                 CURLFORM_FILENAME, imageName.c_str(),
//                 CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "image/png",
//                 CURLFORM_BUFFERPTR, imageData,
//                 CURLFORM_BUFFERLENGTH, fileLength,
//                 CURLFORM_END);

    curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr,

                 CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "imgdata",
                 CURLFORM_FILENAME, imageName.c_str(),
                 CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "application/octet-stream",
                 CURLFORM_BUFFERPTR, imageData,
                 CURLFORM_BUFFERLENGTH, fileLength,
                 CURLFORM_END);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    /* initalize custom header list (stating that Expect: 100-continue is not
         wanted */
//    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Accept: text/xml");
//    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Depth: infinity");
//    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Connection: Keep-Alive");
//    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data");
    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Expect:***");
    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)");

    if(!curl)
        return NULL;

    qDebug() << host.toStdString().c_str();

    /* what URL that receives this POST */

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, host.toStdString().c_str());

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 160);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, OnWriteData);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, headerlist);


    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(res != CURLE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",curl_easy_strerror(res));

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_formfree(formpost);
    curl_slist_free_all(headerlist);
```

Q1: I don't know why  I can't set the curl_header succeeded?

Q2: I already set the `curl_form`, but I can't find the all content from the network capture, no content, but I already set it

[image: screenshot of network capture]

Comment: I just want to  upload image to Server with Some form content .

Comment: Screenshots are a bad idea in questions. The text would have been *far* better.

Comment: Why do you say it returns `No Content` in the text, yet your screenshot says `Continue`?

Comment: May I ask why you are using curl in a Qt project? Qt has native classes for that.

Comment: TKS for your answer!      what's meaning of the Continue?

Comment: and is there any problem in my Code?

Comment: The server sends that continue message after it has validated the headers. It is giving the client the go-ahead to send a potentially large content body.

Comment: I can't set the CURLOPT_HEADER  successed.  I don't know why.

Comment: How do you even know that? You should be checking the return values from those `curl_formadd` calls, and *all* the libcurl function calls for that matter. `curl_formadd` returns 0 on success, an error code on error.

Comment: If you can point out exactly the error code from exactly which call, you have a chance of fixing it quickly.

Comment: i know that from the package whick i catched from Smartsniff. Just seems like the picture i show you before.  I set the header like this : headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Expect:***");
    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)");    But i catched the package show the header havn't been changed.    Even though  the curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, headerlist) return code was 0.

Comment: I removed the Qt tag. Feel free to add it back, but then please  also explain what your question has to do with Qt.

Comment: Smartsniff isn't the solution. Checking the return values from libcurl is likely to lead you to the source of the problem. You can't skip checking everything then expect the next one you bother to check to indicate a problem. *Check them all*.

Comment: i still didn't know is there any problem with my Code to process the HTTP post request.  All of the form_add method return code 0.